# How to call APIs from my JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, typescript, github

I am a 55 yr old novice to API use who grew up in mainframes, scripting, and Wordpress as far as web hosting goes… and I need help. I am stuck because of my lack of knowledge: I can't figure out how to call an API from my application to make embedded checkout work in a headless store - and I want to learn how.

I've exhausted my Google searches and Youtube videos, but since I don't know what to look for when I find it.

To most this is very likely basic, simple and straightforward, for me it's like I'm sitting in a car and have no idea how to turn the engine on.

What I have/know so far:

How to make embedded checkout work:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefronts/embedded-checkout/embedded-checkout-tutorial

and this is where I am lost - I have no idea where to place this code in my vercel & bigcommerce application at

https://github.com/GJB65/commerce1

I humbly acknowledge defeat and would thoroughly appreciate a mentor to help me understand how to turn my embedded checkout engine on.

So the one question I have is "how to call APIs from my application?"

Comment: Try looking for tutorials on how to solve the problem rather than trying to decipher entrie API interfaces. You don't really call APIs, you intereact with them. They have a protocol which you need to follow in order to interact with them, e.g. method of calling them (AJAX/curl/http etc) or format of requests to be made (certain parameters included in the API call you make ) etc. See this page for a guuide to the AJAX protocol for accessing APIs: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Thanks Hektor, I went through these https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefronts/embedded-checkout/embedded-checkout-tutorial and understand how they work - what I'm completely not seeing is how to interact with them from my application. https://20210421.vercel.app/product/data-center-design-and-construction-guide when you add to cart there, I'm lost on how to connect this to our BigCommerce store

Answer (score 0):

if you're referring to the code on the tutorial as what you're not sure where to place -- These are API requests. To test, you can do make these request via a client (like postman - https://www.postman.com/
) or for most of them, you can make these requests directly on our API reference pages in the Test Request section at the bottom of the page. Like this one here:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/channels/channels/createchannel

These resources may also be helpful to you in your learning journey!
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefronts/developers-guide-headless
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefronts/embedded-checkout/embedded-checkout-overview
https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/BigCommerce-for-WordPress-Checkout (if you're using WP as your headless storefront)

Comment: Thanks Heather, can you look at https://20210421.vercel.app/product/data-center-design-and-construction-guide and add it to cart - I'm completely stuck on how to let it check out on our BigCommerce store - what steps do I need to take to have a product added to cart and then be able to perform a check out?

Comment: You should post the code you've tried so far, so that users can help you take the next step.